# Obtain page number according to pages sibling position

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a way via typoscript to obtain the index of the current page in relation to its siblings?

A bit similar to the way we obtain the amount of child pages by using register:count_HMENU_MENUOBJ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer to my own question. 
If there is something better please let me know

```
lib.pagesiblingcount = TEXT
lib.pagesiblingcount {
  numRows.table = pages
  numRows.select.pidInList.data= field: pid
  numRows.select.orderBy = sorting
  numRows.select.andWhere.dataWrap = sorting<={page:sorting}
}
```

Comment: the wrap should have a `|` (pipe) and please do not use spaces at `field:pid`.